# Create virtual screen to have access to extended monitor in old laptop - ubuntu 20.04 wayland nvidia

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, wayland

I have a pc running **ubuntu 20.04** via **NVIDIA 1650** gpu, and my monitor is connected to pc via **HDMI** cable. I want to use my old laptop as a second monitor (extended screen) because I can't buy a new monitor now.
Could someone help me what should I do?
I tried to add a virtual display via `xrandr` or xorg config but still no luck!
All other answers were outdated and not working for `nvidia`.

My goal is to create virtual display as extended screen and connect to it via vnc client from my laptop.

I also used this https://github.com/mrenrich84/vnc_virtual_display_linker repo but I got this error:

```
 >>  N
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  35
  Current serial number in output stream:  35
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  35
  Current serial number in output stream:  36
xrandr: cannot find mode 1920x1080_60.00
```

xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 488mm x 297mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+  59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

nvidia-smi output:

```
Mon Nov 22 22:24:04 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.82.00    Driver Version: 470.82.00    CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
```